# Continue update&render whilst handling windowproc messages

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I've created a win32 C++ app that uses direct2d to plot stuff in a window. In a loop as shown below, I call render and update whilst also peeking at any messages. But when ever I have `WM_COMMAND` that lets `WindowProc` call a `MessageBox()` or `DiaLogBox()`, my update&render loop no longer gets executed and the plot window freezes. Is there a simple fix with another loop structure or do I need to enter the, for me, unknown world of multithreading?

```cpp
    while (message.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        else
        {
            Update();
            BeginDraw();
            Render();
            EndDraw();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: By popular demand I have changed above "ugly" mechanism in to another approach, yet with the same issue

```cpp
bool runGame = true;
while (runGame)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&message);

        if (message.message == WM_QUIT)
            runGame = false;
    }
    
    Update();
    BeginDraw();
    Render();
    EndDraw();
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why your render loop stops executing when this happens?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your rapid reaction. Yes I understand, but I do not know the normal/practical way to solve this.

Comment: Why only render if there's no message? Render whether there was a message or not.

Comment: Indeed not the most sexy way to do it I just discovered. I've also seen another way of writing it with an infinite for-loop for render and the message handling inside in a while statement. But still this stalls the render action?

Comment: If your rendering is stalling forever while dispatching messages then you probably have too many messages to process. Make sure you're responding to `WM_PAINT` and calling `BeginPaint()` / `EndPaint()` properly. Check for timers etc. Fundamentally though, if you dispatch exactly one message and paint exactly one frame every time through the loop, you should never stall as long as your message handling is quick. If it's not then you might need to look into using another thread to do your rendering.

Comment: `my update&render loop no longer gets executed and the plot window freezes.`   Does the program freeze the window when it runs `update&render`?   I have tried to draw a frame of window image in a loop, and there is no freezing problem. Can you post the code of `Update()` and `Render()`?

Comment: Your message loop only runs when the system allows it to. It will frequently forego your implementation and install its own message loop. The observable effect is that your update code stops executing. Setting up a timer that immediately expires to trigger your render code is immune to system-installed message loops. Another bonus with this approach is that rendering becomes a low-priority task. It only gets triggered when there isn't anything more important to do, like handling user input.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions and comments. to explain a bit further, "standard" message handling isn't a problem (responding to mouse movement, buttons clicks, etc). But when the users opens a menu from the menu bar, e.g. "about" or "options" (`WM_COMMAND` calling a `MessageBox` or `DiaLogBox`) the program waits for those boxes to close before returning from to the render part of the loop.

Comment: If you really need to change the UI from "outside" events, then you must use another thread. It depends on your D2D implementation (swapchain, etc.) but this should not pose a particular problem if the device  is marked as multithreaded. Please post more code. Note you can also use Direct Composition / Windows.UI.Composition (Win10 ex: https://gist.github.com/kennykerr/62923cdacaba28fedc4f3dab6e0c12ec). The latter is multithreaded by design.

Comment: Opening a menu causes the system to spin up a nested modal message loop, preempting yours. You don't get to change that. You have to cooperate. The nested message loop will still properly dispatch timer messages, so using a timer is one way to cooperate.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for your comments, as i'm still pretty fresh in the win32 world, how can I use these timer messages from the nested modal loop? 
@SimonMourier my D2D implementation just uses a `CreateHwndRenderTarget()` after I've created a factory with `D2D1CreateFactory()`. And I call the aboutbox with `MessageBox()` in WM_COMMAND using `LOWORD(wParam)`.

Comment: Refer: [Creating a Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-timers#creating-a-timer).    Estimate the rendering time of the window and pass the time as a parameter to [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer).

Comment: Run `Update();BeginDraw();Render();EndDraw();` in the `TIMERPROC`.